# Update basic authentication user store config.toml while server is running

Tags: ballerina

Based on this [document](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-service-basic-authentication-file-user-store/), I am trying to improve security in my ballerina server.

I have two rest APIs like this.

```
isolated resource function post signup(@http:Payload User payload) returns http:Response {
     return signUp(payload);
}

@http:ResourceConfig {
    auth: [
        {
            fileUserStoreConfig: {},
            scopes: ["admin", "developer", "user"]
        }
    ]
}
isolated resource function post login(@http:Payload Credentials payload) returns http:Response {
    return getLoginData(payload);
}
```

When `signup` API is called by a user, the user's username and password are appended to Config.toml.

Ex:

```
[[ballerina.auth.users]]
username = "samankumara008"
password = "1qa2ws3edRF"
scopes=["user"]
```

Then I try to call `login` API by setting the authentication header, but I am getting `401`. When I restart the server it works. I hope without restarting, new entries in Config.toml are not loaded.

How do I fix this problem? How do I use basic authentication file user store in order to overcome this problem?

Comment: In order to overcome this issue I used JWT authentication. Please check this commit. https://github.com/KavinduZoysa/object-monitoring/commit/3e0bc9f4cda5856d5bbd5d222be458f9cf58fe82

Answer (score 3):

It seems this can not be overcome using the basic authentication file user store. The ballerina auth module doesn't read the `Config.toml` file for each request. The given .toml file data are loaded at the server startup time. In this scenario, you may have to look at a different security approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at a different approach to storing the username and password. Instead of using it in a clear-text format in a `Config.toml`, it's better to use another encrypted source. Information stored in .toml files is loaded at the startup, and storing this information on a database may be the best option.